# Swift - Stop TableView Reloading After Dismissing A ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tableview that populates after a fetch request completes. Each row contains a link that opens in a SFSafariViewController. Once the user taps the Done button in the SF Safari VC, the tableview reloads and calls the fetch request again. I don't want this to happen as the fetch request can sometimes take upwards of 15 sec and I'm afraid its doubling my API call count.

Code below - is there anything I can do to prevent the tableview reloading once the Safari VC is dismissed? I tried using a boolean to track it but it simply gets changed again when viewDidLoad /appear gets called. Should I call my fetch request outside of viewdidload/appear somehow?

```
import SafariServices
import UIKit

class ArticlesTVC: UITableViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

var articles = [Article]()

let cellId = "articleCell"

var refresh: Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    registerCell()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    
    refresh = true
    
    if refresh == true {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.fetchArticles()              
            self.refresh = false
        }
    }
   
}

func registerCell() { tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId) }

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {  return articles.count }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    
    let article = articles[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = article.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = article.description
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let article = articles[indexPath.row]
    loadArticle(articleURL: article.url!)
    
}

func loadArticle(articleURL: String) {
    if let url = URL(string: articleURL) {
       
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}

func fetchArticles() {
    
    let baseURL = "url removed for privacy"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "\(baseURL)") else {
        print("url failed")
        return
    }
    
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        
        if let safeData = data {
            self.parseJSON(data: safeData)
        }
        
    }.resume()
}

func parseJSON(data: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(ArticleEnvelope.self, from: data)
        let newsArticles = decodedData.news
        for item in newsArticles {
            let title = item.title
            let description = item.description
            let url = item.url
            let image = item.image
            let published = item.published
            
            let article = Article(title: title, description: description, url: url, image: image, published: published)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.articles.append(article)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            
        }
        print("articles loaded successfully")
    } catch {
        print("Error decoding: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. You are 90% of the way there. Your `viewWillAppear(_:)` method checks a boolean flag `refresh`, and only fetches the data and reloads the table if `refresh == true`. However, it explicitly sets `refresh = true`. Your `viewWillAppear(_:)` function gets called every time you dismiss your other view controller and re-display the table view controller.

Move the line `refresh = true` into `viewDidLoad()`. Problem solved. (`viewDidLoad()` is only called once when the view controller is first created, not each time it is uncovered by dismissing/popping a view controller that is covering it.)

---

### Edit:

Note that in this code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    
    refresh = true
    
    if refresh == true {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { //This bit is not needed
            self.fetchArticles()              
            self.refresh = false
        }
    }
}
```

The call to `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not needed, and will make fetching data slightly slower. `viewWillAppear(_:)` is already always called on the main thread.

Rewrite it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    registerCell()
    refresh = true //Moved from viewWillAppear
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    
    //Remove refresh = true from this function.

    if refresh == true {
        //No need to use DispatchQueue.main.async here
        self.fetchArticles()              
        self.refresh = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Duncan. What I failed to add is that this VC is in a tabBarController. I was instantiating Articles VC in the tabBar's viewWillAppear, so I instead did it in its viewDidLoad and called fetchArticles() there as well, and that seems to have solved it. It also removed the need for the refresh bool check! If you have a sec, do you think its smart to have my Safari VC created in didSelectRow? It seems like an expensive task to have to recreate each time a row is tapped only for it to be destroyed. I'm unable to make it a global variable, however. Thank you so much for your help!